# Errors with alpine linux 3.5 and ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to Dockerize an old RoR4 app using Alpine linux 3.5 to build a ruby on rails 4 docker image but I'm getting several errors related to ssl. I've tried mutple versions of rails 4.x but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous to 2.1, ruby depended on openssl system lib but alpine 3.5+ ships with libressl instead of openssl. You can either remove it and replace with openssl or update your app to ruby 2.3+ to use the default libressl alpine lib.

Adding openssel to alpine(tested with 3.5.0):

```
apk add openssl openssl-dev
```

You should install or reinstall ruby after this.

Edit: Sorry there are several problems with 2.1-2.2 ruby versions and libressl. Try 2.3+ to be safe.

Example bug of 2.2 with libre: https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/40

Comment: I tried installing openssl-dev but the same errors persist

Comment: sorry that's wrong, I forgot to rebuild the machine after adding the RUN apk, that worked thanks!